# Access cant create editable query

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I am making simple MS Access db with 4 tables and forms but when i make query from two tables i cant add new records in this query. I have created relationships and i made all fields type from relationships same format. I dont understand where the problem is. Is there anything that i dont understand or ?

Here are pictures from my relationships and tables

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need to make form from order table and in this form when i select in combobox companyCode i will that in other field automatically companyName fils, but it comes not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 1:n relations need to start from the Primary Keys of the tables, not some "code" column.

E.g. in `order` you should have a (Long Integer) column `companyID` instead of `companyCode`, and define the relation from `company.ID` to `order.companyID`.

Then a query that joins `company` and `order` will be editable.

On a different note: do all your orders contain just one single product? Usually there is a junction table between orders and order items to create a n:m relation.

Comment: I would say "1:n relations need to start from column with unique index", it's not obligatory the Primary Key

Comment: @SergeyS.: You are completely correct, but I didn't want to overcomplicate things. In the OP's table layout, it is best to use the PKs as "relation anchors" (if this is a word).

Comment: IN SQL, you can't use a view that joins tables for update (although there are certain exceptions).  As I understand Access, there is a parallel limitation here.  I may be able to help, but I'm going to have to translate my understanding of SQL into your understanding of Access design view.

Comment: A "normal" Access query is editable, but there are many exceptions. [Here is an overview](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html). In this question it is *The fields in a JOIN are **not indexed** correctly: there is no primary key or unique index on the JOINed fields.* @WalterMitty